# Authentication with ASP.NET Azure WebApp and Managed Service Identity

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App that authenticates users using an Azure AD application.

```
       app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ClientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        var credential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, AppKey);
                        var signedInUserId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        var token = authenticationService.GetADALTokenCache(signedInUserId);
                        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, token);

                        return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, GraphResourceId);
                    }
                }
```

This works 100% fine with the config I pass in. I have now added a Managed Service Identity so that I can grant access to other resources (e.g. Key Vault) to the web app. Sweet.

This makes the app identity I use for the OpenIdConnectAuthentication feel redundant. Am I able to just use the Managed Service Identity to do the authentication instead of having two accounts - one for the MSI and one for the user authentication?

When using the MSI, I don't want to have to supply a ClientID and AppKey from config, I just want it to flow all the way through, using my account for local dev (and running on localhost) and the MSI assigned to the web app when deployed.

I am using the full .Net Framework (i.e. Not Core)

Comment: I don't think so, since the MSI API does not have a way for you to pass in an authorization code AFAIK. So it is limited to service authentication. It is possible to call pretty much any API over app permissions, though you have to assign the appRoleAssignment manually (https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions). It would be possible to similarly assign oauth2PermissionGrants to allow it to call over delegated permissions. But that requires the MSI API to support other flows than just client credentials.

Comment: Per my understanding, when using OpenIdConnectAuthentication, your web application needs to be authorized access, and users need to enter their credentials for logging in. While MSI is used for service-to-azure-service authentication without user interactions. If your web application supports anonymous access, you could just leverage the capabilities provided by MSI. Moreover, you may reuse the generated AAD app by MSI to configure your `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`.